# Error in a custom string concatenation function

Tags: c, string

I am trying to populate a string(arrAna) a 2D array with all the permutations of the string (arr) but I am not getting the desired result.I cannot point out the glitch in my code.

```
void strC(char *a,char b)
{
    int l=0;
    while(a[l]!=NULL) {l++;}
    a[l]=b;
}

for(i=0;i<len;i++)
{
    for(j=i;j<len;j++)
    {
        // printf("%c",arr[j]);
        strC(temp,arr[j]);
        puts(temp);
        /*strcpy(arrAna[x],temp);
        x++;*/
    }
    strcpy(temp," ");printf("After :%s\n",temp);
}
```

Input

```
1
abba
```

Output

```
a
ab
abb
abba
After : 
bbba
bbbab
bbbaba
After : 
bbbaba
bbbabaa
After : 
abbabaa
Desired:
a
ab
abb
abba
b
bb
bba....
```

Comment: `strC` might want to null-terminate the string it builds.

Comment: I indented your code, but the `for` loop does not seem to belong anywhere. You can't have code outside of a function in C.

Comment: I did not post the whole code..just wanted the logic..had a silly mistake of not terminating the string with null...thnx

Comment: `while(a[l]!=NULL)` that's **not** an array of pointers.

Comment: ... assuming you meant to check the string for a terminating `nul` (`'\0'`), you then overwrite the terminator with `a[l]=b;` and fail to write a new terminator with, say `a[l+1]='\0';`

Comment: ... and anyway, please don't use a single `l` (ell) as a variable name. You have to squint to distinguish from `1` (one).